# Are the Rabbis currently talking?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag

What is the source for talking about the past writings of rabbis in present tense? E.g. rashi says. Instead of said.
I understand the concept to be something along the lines of this [pasuk](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6.6):

> And these words that I command you today shall be upon your heart.

Is my assumption correct, and is this talked about anywhere?

Comment: דובב שפתי ישנים, אמר רבי יוחנן בן תורתה, אף על פי שמת שפתותיו רוחשות עליו בקבר, מאי טעמא, דובב שפתי ישנים.
https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shir_HaShirim_Rabbah.7.10.1?lang=bi

Comment: This is not unique to Judaism. If you read history books, for example, historians' opinions are often quoted in the present tense.

Comment: "The other permissible use of present tense is when the person made such a notable artistic or literary contribution that their legacy is still very much alive."
 https://commonreader.wustl.edu/speak-of-the-dead-in-present-tense/#:~:text=The%20other%20permissible%20use%20of%20present%20tense%20is%20when%20the%20person%20made%20such%20a%20notable%20artistic%20or%20literary%20contribution%20that%20their%20legacy%20is%20still%20very%20much%20alive.

Comment: It's called *présent de narration*.

Comment: @magicker72 is this a linguistic rule then?

Comment: @Harel13 so it's not unique to rabbis. As in there's no concept of the torah being currently taught ?

Comment: There might be, but it's a widespread phenomenon that may not have originated in Judaism.